# c++ unfamiliar use of ':' in declaration

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty understanding some existing code in order to update it.  I am not familiar with the use of colons and the program name in this declaration.  The program is called rbac4xml which seems to be called in the declaration and then colons are used to access the Roles type and pointer.

```
void output_keyrings(const std::vector<rbacp4xml:Role:*> &roles, const rbacp4xml::Keys &keys );
```

I have tried to find this in reference books and google, but now sadly must ask :)  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: A guess: a pointer to member?

Comment: I don't know what `rbacp4xml` is, but I don't think it's a "program". Are you sure this is standard C++?

Comment: `rbacp4xml` doesn't seem to be available on Google, your question is the only mention of such a namespace. If it's some code in your company's / school's codebase, how about asking the person who wrote it?

Comment: I have looked at some further classes and I think it may also be declared as a namespace, but I have never seen a single colon use to resolve a namespace.

Comment: That said, most everything I've read points to single colons only being used to denote inheritance or a constructor's initializer list. I wouldn't put it past C++ to have grown another use for it but it still might simply be invalid code. (It's not that far away from `rbacp4xml::Role* which would be fine.) Does it actually compile?

Comment: Actually a reason it might compile is that `name:` denotes a goto label. (As well as bitfields in C.) I'm not sure whether it makes sense to put them into the middle of a parameter list but for all you know your compiler might accept it.

Comment: I just took a quick look through the C++ grammar, and I don't see any uses of a single `:` consistent with this usage -- particularly not followed by a `*` and a `>`. It's possible I missed something, but I strongly suspect this is not standard C++. As @millimoose suggested, ask the person who wrote it and/or the person who asked you to update it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot easily ask the author, long moved away.  Fortunately, I can just rewrite it in a more standard way and make it work.  I was mostly curious about this syntax as I have never seen that usage before.  Many thanks for all your responses, as it seems to be non-standard I will move on.  Best regards.

Comment: FWIW I can't get this to compile: http://ideone.com/ObPEz7 - maybe your build isn't even touching that file.

Comment: It is in main.cpp, the program does compile and execute correctly, however there may be a hack somewhere that I haven't seen yet that makes it work.  This is my first post to stackoverflow and I am very impressed and grateful for the quality and enthusiasm of the contributors.  Thanks again.

Comment: This does not look at all like valid C++. The `rbacp4xml` symbol looks like it could be a namespace, or class with some scoped typedefs. And especially given you have `rbacp4xml::Keys`, you would expect `rbacp4xml::Role` (with the double colon). I'm very surprised this compiles, especially with `:*` after `Role`. Can you run the compiler with preprocessing only and see if it expands to something else that is valid? (eg. `gcc -E`) It would be interesting to see what that turns up, ie. if there is a macro involved.

Comment: Post more code, with more context. Especially what `rbacp4xml` is, and any clues about `Role`, then amybe we can figure it out.

Comment: Can :* be a very obscure compiler-specific digraph ?

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
const rbacp4xml::Keys &keys
```

makes it clear that rbacp4xml is a class that has a member type called Keys.

The declaration

```
const std::vector<rbacp4xml:Role:*> &roles
```

is not valid C++ as far as I know. Since #defines don't allow colons inside, you may be sure rbacp4xml:Role: has not been redefined in that way. Even if you define Role as an empty definition, i.e.

```
#define Role
```

you are not allowed to write rbacp4xml:Role: to get rbacp4xml::.

So I strongly suspect it's a spelling mistake. It should probably read:

```
const std::vector<rbacp4xml::Role *> &roles
```

This would mean you create a vector of pointers, each of which points to a variable of type rbacp4xml::Role, i.e. there is a typedef Role within the class rbacp4xml.

If your code does compile, maybe this part is by-passed somehow. Try putting a #error in front of the declaration. If your code still compiles, you'll know it is by-passed. It may be by-passed when put inside a #ifdef..#endif, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid portable C++. May be it's a custom extension or this code is run through some preprocessor before being sent to a C++ compiler.